# How to test auth headers with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am attempting to test the auth header when doing an api call:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import ApiClient from './apiClient';
import ApiService from './apiService';

jest.mock('./apiClient', () => {
  return {
    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer test token' },
    get: jest.fn()
  };
});

describe('apiService methods', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    ApiClient.get.mockImplementation((url: string) => {
      return Promise.resolve({ data: mockData });
    });
  });

  it('getArticles method call', () => {
    ApiService.getArticles(jest.fn(), 1, 3, 'latest', 'news', 'selectedNews');

    expect(axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization).toBe(
      'Bearer test token'
    ); // THIS GIVES UNDEFINED SO THE TEST FAILS

    expect(ApiClient.get).toBeCalledWith(
      '/content?type=article&page=1&limit=3&sort=latest&facet=news&article_category=selectedNews'
    );
  });
});
```

This is what I have on `ApiClient` to request the header:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import envs from '../../config/index.json';

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: envs.data.data.centralApi.baseUrl + apiVersion
});

client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
  `adal.access.token.key${envs.data.data.adal.clientId}`
)}`;
```

So I need to test that the `Authorization` header is properly send when the api call is performed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Since `ApiService.getArticles` is an asynchronous call, you should set your expectations within a `then` clause.

For example:

```
  it('getArticles method call', () => {
    ApiService.getArticles(jest.fn(), 1, 3, 'latest', 'news', 'selectedNews').then(() => {
        expect(axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization).toBe(
        'Bearer test token'
        ); // THIS GIVES UNDEFINED SO THE TEST FAILS

        expect(ApiClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        '/content?type=article&page=1&limit=3&sort=latest&facet=news&article_category=selectedNews'
        );  // Note the use of "toHaveBeenCalledWith" instead of "toBeCalledWith"
    });
});
```

If your project supports ES6 syntax, you could also use `async`/`await`:

```
it('getArticles method call', async () => {

    await ApiService.getArticles(jest.fn(), 1, 3, 'latest', 'news', 'selectedNews');

    expect(axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization).toBe(
      'Bearer test token'
    ); // THIS GIVES UNDEFINED SO THE TEST FAILS

    expect(ApiClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      '/content?type=article&page=1&limit=3&sort=latest&facet=news&article_category=selectedNews'
    );

});
```

You could also use a library like [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) to mock HTTP requests in tests.

For instance:

```
npm install --save-dev nock
```

```
import nock from 'nock';
// ...your other imports

const baseUrl = 'https://some-base-url.com';
const mockRequest = nock(baseUrl);

describe('apiService methods', () => {

  it('getArticles method call', () => {
    const url = "/content?type=article&page=1&limit=3&sort=latest&facet=news&article_category=selectedNews";

    mockRequest.matchHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer test token').get(url).reply(200, '');

    ApiService.getArticles(jest.fn(), 1, 3, 'latest', 'news', 'selectedNews').then(function (response) { 
        expect(response).to.equal('');
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Incorrect header:', error);
    });

  });

});
```

If the header doesn't match, an error will be thrown.

One last thing - when you use `jest.mock()`, you're effectively overriding the file being imported. It's generally meant to override specific methods in the imported file with mock methods. It could be that by overriding `apiClient` you're not reaching the line of code where you set the default `axios` headers:

```
client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
  `adal.access.token.key${envs.data.data.adal.clientId}`
)}`; // Not being reached because `apiClient` is being overriden
```

Drop a console log in there to make sure you're getting there.